# Why won't python update function value?

Tags: python, function, polygon

I am trying to make a table in python that asks a user for a side length of a polygon and then gives the area of that polygon when it's number of sides is between 3-9. My problem is that, in the report function, I have to give a different area for each polygon with a different number of sides but when i run it, the area is always the same even when the number of sides of the polygon has changed.

```
import math

def main():
    side_length = get_side_length()
    report(side_length)

def get_side_length():
    length = int(input('Enter a side length: '))
    return length

def report(a):
    num_sides = 2
    each_area = polygon_area(a)
    print('side length\t'+ 'number of sides\t'+ 'area')
    while num_sides < 9:
        num_sides += 1
        print(a, num_sides, each_area, sep='\t\t', end='\n')

def polygon_area(sl):
    for num_sides in range(3, 10):
        area = (num_sides * sl * sl) / (4 * math.tan(math.pi / num_sides))
        return area

main()
```

Comment: Well, your code only calls `polygon_area` once.  If you want to get multiple areas, it stands to reason you ought to be calling that function multiple times.  It also stands to reason it should accept `num_sides` as an argument.

Comment: Putting a `return` statement unconditionally inside a loop is a bad idea, because `return` causes the function to terminate immediately. For example, `for i in range(10): return i` will return `0`, not `[0,1,2 ... 9]`.

Comment: change your `return` in your `polygon_area` to a `yield`